# ActiveAdmin belongs_to/has_one relationship breaking show page of one of the models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, activeadmin

I have two models one is the Project model and the other one is the ProjectSyndication model, code looks something like this:

```
class Project
  has_one :project_syndication
end


class ProjectSyndication
  belongs_to :project
end


ActiveAdmin.register Project, as: 'Offering' do

end

ActiveAdmin.register ProjectSyndication do
  belongs_to :offering, parent_class: Project
end
```

This code gives me an error when I go to the show page of a ProjectSyndication, which is the following:

```
undefined method `project_syndications' for #<Project:0x007fc309a972b0>
```

I did just a bit of digging and for the hell of it created an empty project_syndications method in my Project model then got the following error:

```
undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass
```

So I can deduce that ActiveAdmin is treating this association like a has_many association and trying to find the ProjectSyndication after finding all the project syndications of one project, which won't work.

I solved the problem by making the following method under the Project model

```
def project_syndications
  ProjectSyndication.where(project_id: id)
end
```

This works fine, but I feel it is not the right way to do it. I looked through the ActiveAdmin docs, but have not been able to find much. What I asked is for the right way to fix the issue or if this is a bug/feature from ActiveAdmin.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but did you find a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague.
Maybe provide your database migrations as well.

I would check the following (vague guesses):

```
class Project; has_one :project_syndication; end
```

=> This inidicates your db has the field projects.project_syndication_id

=> Maybe **try "has_many"** there?

```
ActiveAdmin.register Project, as: 'Offering' do; end;
```

=> Case Offering vs offering below

=> Redundant code? (remove it)

```
ActiveAdmin.register ProjectSyndication do; belongs_to :offering, parent_class: Project; end
```

=> Redundant code? (remove it)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. But i'm not sure what you are saying, the Project model does not have a project_syndication_id, that's actually in the ProjectSyndication model which has a project_id attribute, indicating that a project has one project_syndication. as you see here: [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) . 

The code you referred to redundant is the ActiveAdmin code, if I remove it ActiveAdmin won't work.

Comment: If you have syndications.project_id, a Project surely can has_many syndications... Probably that is the culprit after all?

Comment: We do not need a has_many relationship, a project only has one syndication. why would I go for a has_many relationship?

Comment: Then maybe do Project.has_one(:syndication, :dependent => :destroy) and Syndication.belongs_to(:project)